# Uniform convergence, area of convergence and Weierstrass criteria

Tags: calculus

I want to ask two questions:

1. Is there a relation between the area of convergence of a functional series and the uniform convergence and the convergence at all?
2. Can I prove that a functional series is not uniform convergent using the Weierstrass criteria? For example if the series which we majorate with is not convergent(the harmonic series for example). In this case does it mean that the functional series is not uniform convergent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). You have to be careful how you ask this question. It doesn't make sense to say a functional series uniformly converges at a particular point. Rather, we talk about uniform convergence on a set. It's not the case that the functional series converges uniformly on the set of points where it converges. Of course it converges uniformly on some subsets of the set of points where it converges (e.g. a finite subset).

2).The Weierstrass criterion most certainly cannot be used to disprove uniform convergence (in the way you described). I can start with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n^2}$ which converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ but majorize each term by $\frac{x}{n^2} \le \frac{x}{n}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n}$ of course doesn't converge.

Comment: The uniform convergence is related to a limit function. The convergence area of a functional series has nothing to do with that limit function. So the two things doesn't have something in common. Am I right?

Comment: And how can I prove that a functional series is not convergent? For example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$ where x belongs to [1,+inf)

Comment: You seem to be confused. The limit function is only defined where the functional series converges. Let's say we have $f(x) = \sum_n f_n(x)$ for $x$ such that $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges. Then for a set $A$ of $x$'s, we say that $\sum_n f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N$ such that $|f(x)-\sum_{n \le N} f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ in $A$.

Comment: Also, if $s \ge 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$, which we know diverges.

Comment: So if the series that we minorate with is divergent we can sat that the functional series is not uniformlt convergent?

Comment: And is it true that the domain of the limit function is the area of convergence of the functional series?

Comment: I was showing that the sum does not converge, for any $x \ge 1$. In particular, it doesn't make sense to talk about whether it is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Yea, I guess the domain of the limit function is the set of convergence of the functional series

Comment: I think $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}≥\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is not true

Comment: @spyer Oh, you're absolutely right. I apologize. I was thinking $s < 1$. Let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^x}$. Then $f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ is well defined for $x \in (1,\infty)$. I don't think it's the case that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $(1,\infty)$. On the other hand, I think that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,\infty)$ for any fixed $a > 1$.

Comment: And how  to prove that it is not uniform convergent over [1,+inf)

Comment: Suppose that there were some $N$ such that $|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^x}| < 1$ for all $x \in (1,\infty)$ (I'm using the definition of uniform convergence with $\epsilon = 1$). So, $|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}| \le 1$ for each $x > 1$. But this clearly can't be true. The intuition is that as $x \to 1$, we'll have the harmonic series which diverges (note we can't plug in $x=1$ since we are looking at $(1,\infty)$). continued...

Comment: A way to make this rigorous would be to first take some positive integer $M \ge N+1$ such that $\sum_{n=N+1}^M \frac{1}{n} > 2$. We then have $|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}| = \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x} \ge \sum_{n=N+1}^M \frac{1}{n^x}$. And by taking $x$ really close to $1$, by continuity, we can make $\sum_{n=N+1}^M \frac{1}{n^x} > 1$ (since the limit as $x \to 1$ is $2$). This is a contradiction.